# What's the best way to test whether an sklearn model has been fitted?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

What's the most elegant way to check whether an sklearn model has been fitted? i.e. whether its `fit()` function has been called after it was instantiated, or not.

Comment: i'm not sure if I understand what you want, but a `for loop` will do the job!!!

Comment: Just to clarify, the person below answered perfectly.

Comment: I've edited the question so that it is clear, can someone please unclose it? It's a good question and I have an alternate answer that I cannot add since it is still closed.

Comment: The correct answer is to use scikit's [check_is_fitted](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html)

Comment: @sapo_cosmico, thanks for bringing up `check_is_fitted`. I updated the answer with more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scikit-learn how to check if model (e.g. TfidfVectorizer) has been already fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369709/scikit-learn-how-to-check-if-model-e-g-tfidfvectorizer-has-been-already-fit)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
from sklearn.exceptions import NotFittedError

for model in models:
    try:
        model.predict(some_test_data)
    except NotFittedError as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Ideally you would check the results of `model.predict` against expected results but if all you want to know if wether the model is fitted or not that should suffice.

#### **Update**:

Some commenters have suggested using [check_is_fitted](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html). I consider `check_is_fitted` an [internal method](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/glossary.html#term-fitted). Most algorithms will call `check_is_fitted` inside their predict method which in turn might raise `NotFittedError` if needed. The problem with using `check_is_fitted` directly is that it is model specific, i.e. you need to know which members to check depending on your algorithm. For example:

```
╔════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Tree models    ║ check_is_fitted(self, 'tree_')             ║
║ Linear models  ║ check_is_fitted(self, 'coefs_')            ║
║ KMeans         ║ check_is_fitted(self, 'cluster_centers_')  ║
║ SVM            ║ check_is_fitted(self, 'support_')          ║
╚════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

and so on. So in general I would recommend calling `model.predict()` and letting the specific algorithm handle the best way to check whether it is already fitted or not.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.

Comment: @elyase is right for sklearn. There are others: `from xgboost.core import XGBoostError` and `from lightgbm.sklearn import LightGBMError`, for instance

Comment: @GeorgeFisher: True, but the OP did specify sklearn specifically.

Comment: This is not a good solution, as your `try` might fail because of a problem with `some_test_data`. 

For instance, if `some_test_data = "duck"`, the model might be completely fine, but will fail. You will then report the wrong error. 

Use [check_is_fitted](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html) instead

Comment: Along the same lines with @elyase, see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html

Comment: @sapo_cosmico, the except clause only catches `NotFittedError` so this error will be reported in the correct situation. Given that `.predict()` calls `check_is_fitted` which then raises `NotFittedError` I can't think of a situation where the wrong error would be displayed but please feel free to correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: Note that `check_is_fitted()` does not necessarily have to specify the attribute. From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html) of the `attribute` parameter:  "_If `None`, `estimator` is considered fitted if there exist an attribute that ends with a underscore and does not start with double underscore._"

Answer (score 10):

I do this for classifiers:

```
def check_fitted(clf): 
    return hasattr(clf, "classes_")
```

Answer (score 4):

Cribbing directly from the scikit-learn source code for the `check_is_fitted` function (similar logic to @david-marx, but a little simpler):

```
def is_fitted(model):
    '''
    Checks if a scikit-learn estimator/transformer has already been fit.
    
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    model: scikit-learn estimator (e.g. RandomForestClassifier) 
        or transformer (e.g. MinMaxScaler) object
        
    
    Returns
    -------
    Boolean that indicates if ``model`` has already been fit (True) or not (False).
    '''
    
    attrs = [v for v in vars(model)
             if v.endswith("_") and not v.startswith("__")]
    
    return len(attrs) != 0
```

Answer (score 3):

This is sort of a greedy approach, but it should be fine for most if not all models. The only time this might not work is for models that set an attribute ending in an underscore prior to being fit, which I'm pretty sure would violate scikit-learn convention so this should be fine.

```
import inspect

def is_fitted(model):
        """Checks if model object has any attributes ending with an underscore"""
        return 0 < len( [k for k,v in inspect.getmembers(model) if k.endswith('_') and not k.startswith('__')] )
```

Comment: interesting solution! Goes along the lines of http://scikit-learn.org/dev/glossary.html#term-fitted. +1

Answer (score 2):

this function to check if a scikit-learn model is fitted by comparing it to a new instance of the model.

```
def is_fitted(model):
    return not len(dir(model)) == len(dir(type(model)()))

model = OneHotEncoder()
print(is_fitted(model)) #False
model.fit_transform(data)
print(is_fitted(model)) #True
```