# Scikit-Learn Voting Classifier Predictor Scores Always 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I am trying to compare the validation set performance of an ensemble classifier with the individual predictors that make up the ensemble.

I've been following the code for [Exercise 8 from this notebook](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/07_ensemble_learning_and_random_forests.ipynb) to build a hard `VotingClassifier` with a `LinearSVC`, `RandomForestClassifier`, `ExtraTreesClassifier`, and `MLPClassifier` for version 1 of the MNIST Digits dataset using `sklearn`'s `fetch_openml` API.

I trained the ensemble and evaluated it by calling its `score` function with validation data, and got a score of 0.97. So I'm certain the ensemble and, by extension, the individual predictors have been trained/fit.

But when I try using list comprehension to call `score` on the individual fitted `estimators_` in this ensemble, like so

```
[estimator.score(X_val, y_val) for estimator in voting_clf.estimators_]
```

I always get a result of 0.0 for each predictor, even if I evaluate on the training data.

I've confirmed the sub-estimators in `estimators_` have been fit using the `predict` method as described in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884009/whats-the-best-way-to-test-whether-an-sklearn-model-has-been-fitted?answertab=votes#tab-top).

I have also trained the same estimators individually and evaluated them with the same method. This seems to work as scores are similar to the ones in the tutorial notebook.

Am I referencing the wrong list of sub-estimators in the ensemble object?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please post the exact code you are using here, and not in an external link - see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As is, it is impossible to say where exactly your problem lies

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding

```
mnist.target = mnist.target.astype(np.uint8)
```

after loading the MNIST dataset.

It works for me.